# Google Analytics usar API .NET para obter informações de pageviews

Tags: .net, api, google-analytics-api

Como faço para buscar informações de Pageview de uma determinada URL de meu site via programação usando alguma API do Google Analitcs.

Vale ressaltar que já tenho todo o site configurado no Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de bastante pesquisa, e algumas dores de cabeças, consegui realizar o procedimento da seguinte forma.

### DEPENDÊNCIAS

- Monitoramento: [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com)
- API Google Analytics: [API de Relatórios Principais](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)
- Pacote Nuget: [Google.Apis.Analytics.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3) Documentado [aqui](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3).

### INSTRUÇÕES BÁSICAS

A integração não é exatamente difícil.
Praticamente, você terá que seguir alguns passos para conseguir o objetivo.

Vou listá-los abaixo, e estou partindo do pré-suposto que você já tenha um projeto criado (sendo monitorado) no Google Analytics.

1) **Ativar a Biblioteca Google Analytics**
Console Google Developer => Seu projeto => Biblioteca de API's => Buscar Analytics API => Ativar

2) **Criar conta de Serviço** (Com chave P12)
Console Google Developer => Seu projeto => IAM e Admin => Contas de Serviços => Criar Conta de Serviço
OBS: Ao criar a chave ela deve ser baixada.

3) **Permitir esta conta de serviço acesse seus perfis / sites no Google Analytics**
Google Analytics => Administração => Selecionar Conta/Propriedade/Vista da Propriedade => Gerenciamento de Usuários (Da vista da propriedade)

4) **Install Pacote Nuget** 
[Google.Apis.Analytics.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3)
`PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Analytics.v3`

5) **Show me the code!**

> Ao instanciar a classe, passe o LocalPath de onde estiver salva a chaveP12 que você baixou na etapa 2 e o id da conta que você criou na etapa 3.
>
> Você irá consumir principalmente o método `GetAnalyticsData`. Seus parâmetros precisam ser entendidos. Veja mais em referências sobre dimensões, filtros e métricas.
>
> O Filtro, está via hard-code neste código no método `BuildAnalyticRequest`. Implemente para que seja um parâmetro também.

```
public class IntegracaoAnalyticsAPI
    {
        public AnalyticsService Service { get; set; }

        public IntegracaoAnalyticsAPI(string pathChaveP12, string idDaConta)
        {
            try
            {
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pathChaveP12, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);


                var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(idDaConta)
                   {
                       Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }
                   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                Service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                    ApplicationName = "NOME DA SUA APLICAÇÃO"
                });
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex1)
            {
               //"Error: The directory specified could not be found."
            }
            catch (IOException ex2)
            {
               //"Error: A file in the directory could not be accessed."
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex3)
            {
               //"File must be a .cer file. Program does not have access to that type of file."
            }
            catch (Exception ex4)
            {
               // "xiiii.."
            }
        }

        public AnalyticDataPoint GetAnalyticsData(string profileId, string[] dimensions, string[] metrics, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            AnalyticDataPoint data = new AnalyticDataPoint();
            if (!profileId.Contains("ga:"))
                profileId = string.Format("ga:{0}", profileId);

            //Make initial call to service.
            //Then check if a next link exists in the response,
            //if so parse and call again using start index param.
            GaData response = null;
            do
            {
                int startIndex = 1;
                if (response != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextLink))
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri(response.NextLink);
                    var paramerters = uri.Query.Split('&');
                    string s = paramerters.First(i => i.Contains("start-index")).Split('=')[1];
                    startIndex = int.Parse(s);
                }

                var request = BuildAnalyticRequest(profileId, dimensions, metrics, startDate, endDate, startIndex);
                response = request.Execute();
                data.ColumnHeaders = response.ColumnHeaders;
                data.Rows.AddRange(response.Rows);

            } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextLink));

            return data;
        }

        private DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest BuildAnalyticRequest(string profileId, string[] dimensions, string[] metrics,
                                                                            DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int startIndex)
        {
            DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = Service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                                                                endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), string.Join(",", metrics));
            request.Dimensions = string.Join(",", dimensions);
            request.StartIndex = startIndex;
            request.Filters = "ga:pagePath=@seuFiltro";
            return request;
        }

        public IList<Profile> GetAvailableProfiles()
        {
            var response = Service.Management.Profiles.List("~all", "~all").Execute();
            return response.Items;
        }

        public class AnalyticDataPoint
        {
            public AnalyticDataPoint()
            {
                Rows = new List<IList<string>>();
            }

            public IList<GaData.ColumnHeadersData> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
            public List<IList<string>> Rows { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

EXEMPLO DE USO:

```
var analytics = new IntegracaoAnalyticsAPI("LOCAL_PATH_DA_CHAVE_P12", "ID_CONTA");
var dados = analytics.GetAnalyticsData("ID_DA_VISTA", new string[] { "ga:userType" }, new string[] { "ga:pageviews" }, DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30), DateTime.Now.Date);
```

### REFERÊNCIAS

1) [StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306872/use-google-analytics-api-to-show-information-in-c-sharp) Base deste processo, porém tive que ajustar algumas coisas.
2) Good [Reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/how-to-fetch-google-analytics-statistics-and-display-it-in-y/)
3) Construção de **[Query Online](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer)** (Muito útil para ajudar a entender o retorno da sua query).
4) Trabalhando com **[Filtros](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)**
5) Entendendo as **[Métricas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#metrics)**
6) Entendendo as **[Dimensões](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#dimensions)**